# how to get the current map coordinates?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps

I have yandex map on page. For this map i bind event handler 'actionend'.

I need in this handler get current coordinates of map center. Please help me make it.

[live demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/1rk2g0dv/9/)

Code:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

var myMap;

function init(){     
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        controls: [],
        zoom: 18
    });   

    myMap.events.add('actionend', function (e) {
        console.log('stop action');
        console.log('print current coords of map center???????????????');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the center coord by calling the `getCenter()` method, like this:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

var myMap;

function init(){     
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        controls: [],
        zoom: 18
    });   

    myMap.events.add('actionend', function (e) {
       console.log(e.originalEvent.map.getCenter())
    });
};
```

See this [doc](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#method_detail__getCenter).